# The determinant of the hessian matrix

Tags: multivariable-calculus

when looking for a min/max/saddle point we you the notation $D: f_{xx}\cdot f_{yy}-(f_{xy}^2)$ which is the determinant of the hessian matrix.

can I use $f_{yx}$ instead of $f_{xy}$ is there importance to the order of derivatives in this case?

Comment: Mixed partials are equal (under mild assumptions).

Comment: @littleO we are assuming this when writing $D: f_{xx}\cdot f_{yy}-(f_{xy}^2)$? else it was $ f_{xx}\cdot f_{yy}-f_{xy}\cdot f_{yx}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under mild assumptions, $f_{xy} = f_{yx}$.  The order of the derivatives does not matter, you get the same answer either way.  More information can be found [here](http://calculus.subwiki.org/wiki/Clairaut's_theorem_on_equality_of_mixed_partials), for example.

You could use $f_{yx}$ instead of $f_{xy}$ and it would make no difference because $f_{yx} = f_{xy}$.